# Android Studio gradle/build configuration for best performance with 32 GB RAM

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

So I upgraded my PC from 16 GB to 32 GB RAM and want to find which settings are the best for projects in Android Studio

Based on one of Google official projects https://github.com/android/nowinandroid/blob/main/gradle.properties

I added the following to my `gradle.properties` and increased GB values:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx12g -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=2g

# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
org.gradle.parallel=true

# Not encouraged by Gradle and can produce weird results. Wait for isolated projects instead.
org.gradle.configureondemand=false

# Enable caching between builds.
org.gradle.caching=true

# Enable configuration caching between builds.
org.gradle.unsafe.configuration-cache=true
```

Should I keep  the following lines or can it slower the Android Studio/Build, if it does some caching on the disk, so mb is it better to keep everything in RAM instead?

```
org.gradle.configureondemand=false
org.gradle.caching=true
org.gradle.unsafe.configuration-cache=true
```

Android Studio memory settings:

[image]